# (half solve)Why copy file reference to clipboard programmatically only working for system folder in MacOS?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, privileges, nspasteboard

## Solution

add this code `pasteboard.data(forType: .fileURL)` after `pasteboard.writeObjects(emptyArray)`, it will work.

But I don't know why?

---

**System Verison: MacOS Ventura 13.0**

**copy.swift**

```swift
 #!/usr/bin/swift

 import Cocoa

 private func copyToClipBoard(path :String) {
     let pasteboard = NSPasteboard.general

     var emptyArray = [NSPasteboardWriting]()
     emptyArray.append(NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path))

     pasteboard.clearContents()

     pasteboard.writeObjects(emptyArray)

 }

 copyToClipBoard(path: CommandLine.arguments[1])
```

If I run `swift copy.swift /Users/USER/Downloads/FILE`, paste to chat window for third-party applications is working.

If I run `swift copy.swift /Users/USER/tmp/FILE`, cannot paste to chat window for third-party applications, application occur no permission error, I already give full access disk to this application.

What's the difference between **Downloads** and **tmp**?

How can I make copy file reference programmatically working for any folder?

Comment: Can you manually copy the file in the Finder and paste in the third-party app?

Comment: @Willeke yes manually is normal, now I have a solution, but I don't know why, maybe you can help me explain

Comment: I don't know. Maybe it's a sandbox thing.

Comment: @Willeke yes, you are right, I am also aware of the problem, but I cannot found about script sandbox information.